Question about the proof of the Geometric Hahn-Banach Theorem
I am reading the proof of the Geometric Hahn-Banach Theorem presented in my textbook (https://lucris.lub.lu.se/ws/portalfiles/portal/124277769/HormanderLinearFunctionalAnalysis.pdf, page 12) and have some questions about it.
I will first introduce some definitions.
Definition A subset $A$ of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is convex if for any $x,y\in V$, the set
$$
\{t\in\mathbb{R}: x + ty\in A\}
$$
is an interval. It is linearly open if the interval is open.
(Geometric Hahn-Banach Theorem) Let $A$ be a nonempty linearly open subset of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $V_1$ be a subspace of $V$ which doesn't intersect $A$. Then there exists a hyperplane $V_2$ containing $V_1$ which doesn't intersect $A$.
The proof goes the following way.
Proof $1.$ Suppose that $\dim(V) = 2$. Then we only need to consider the case when $V_1 = \{0\}$. It's easy to find a line through $0$ which doesn't intersect $A$.
$2.$ Generally, let $V' = V/V_1$ and $A'$ be the image of $A$ in $V'$. Then $A'$ is linearly open following from the fact that $A$ is linearly open. We can find a straight line $W'$ in $V'$ which doesn't intersect $A'$ because of our first step...
I didn't understand the last point. How did it follow from the first step when the dimension of $V$ is $2$? I am bad at quotient spaces and couldn't get this part of the proof.
Any help is welcome. Thanks!

You missed out the assumption about convexity in the theorem.

@CheeHan I think $V_1$ is linearly open implies that it is convex?

See Definition 1.4.6 on the same page.

@CheeHan The book seems to define the term "linearly open" only for convex sets. The OP, however, seems to be defining $A$ to be linearly open if ${t\in\mathbb{R}: x + ty\in A}$ is an open interval, for all $x, y \in V$. This, of course, would make "linearly open" a stronger condition than convexity. So, what they wrote, in the context of this post, is not incorrect.

The proof does have a nice structure, but the way it's written makes it seem a little counterintuitive. Essentially there are three cases (though the proof swallows the middle case somewhat):

Prove the $\dim V = 2$ case (where $V_1$ is necessarily trivial, or there's nothing to prove).
Prove the more general case where $V_1$ is trivial.
Prove the most general case, where $V_1$ can be anything.

Cases 2 and 3 are reduced to 1 and 2 respectively. The quotient space argument is only necessary for the reduction from case 3 to case 2; by quotienting out $V_1$, you map to case 2 under the quotient map.
To get from case 2 to case 1, the proof simply chooses an arbitrary two-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$. Necessarily, it contains $V_1 = \{0\}$. If $W$ fails to intersect $A$, then you're done: $W$ is a larger superspace of $V_1$ that is disjoint from $A$. If it does intersect $A$, then we are in case 1 now, with $A$ replaced by $A \cap W$ (it is convex and linearly open - prove it!). So, by case 1, we can extend $V_1$ to a line, contained in $W$, that misses $W \cap A$, and hence all of $A$.
Hope that helps.
